# Problema con funciones y arrays en C

Tags: c

No entiendo porque el programa no realiza lo que ordeno hacer en las funciones y simplemente se imprime por pantalla los dos "printf" que uso de prueba en el main.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10
void leerVect(int vect[MAX]);
void escribirVect (int v[MAX], int tam);


int main ()
{
    int v[MAX], tam=10;
    printf("empezamos\n");
    void leerVect(v);
    void escribirVect (v, tam);
    printf("Terminamos");
    return 0;
}

void leerVect(int v[MAX])
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<MAX && v[i]!=0; i++)
    {
        printf("Introduzca el valor de v[%d]\n", i);
        scanf("%d", &v[i]);
    }
}

void escribirVect (int v[MAX], int tam)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<tam; i++)
    {
        printf("El valor de v[%d] es: %d \n", i, v[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [edit](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Como dijo *Jack el Destripador*, vamos por partes:

```
int main( ) {
  ...
  void leerVect(v);
  void escribirVect (v, tam);
  ...
}
```

Ahí **no** estás llamando a ninguna función; **las estás declarando otra vez**. De hecho, el compilador seguramente te genere algún que otro *warning*:

> In function 'main':
>   warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
>   `void leerVect(v);`
>   
>   warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
>   `void escribirVect (v, tam);`

Para llamarlas, **no es necesario** indicar el tipo de retorno, basta con su nombre y sus argumentos:

```
int main( ) {
  ...
  leerVect(v);
  escribirVect (v, tam);
  ...
}
```

Ahora, veamos tu bucle de lectura:

```
for( i = 0; i < MAX && v[i] != 0; i++ )
```

¿ Esa comparación `v[i] != 0` que hace ahí ? Puesto que no inicializas tu *formación*, contendrá valores aleatorios; **no** tienes forma de saber si tendrá o no un `0`.

Así pues, eliminamos esa comprobación *curiosa*:

```
for( i = 0; i < MAX; i++ )
```

Listo, ya debe de funcionar como se espera :-)

Answer (score 0):

Como dice Trauma, primero se debe llamar a las funciones (en este caso `leerVect(v)` y `escribirVect (v, tam)`, no declararlos dentro del main), segundo se debe recorrer el vector de la misma forma que se recorre y ternero la variable `tam` no es necesaria

El programa corregido quedaría así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10
void leerVect(int vect[MAX]);
void escribirVect (int v[MAX]);


int main ()
{
    int v[MAX];
    printf("empezamos\n");
    leerVect(v);
    escribirVect (v);
    printf("Terminamos");
    return 0;
}

void leerVect(int v[MAX])
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        printf("Introduzca el valor de v[%d]\n", i);
        scanf("%d", &v[i]);
    }
}

void escribirVect (int v[MAX])
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        printf("El valor de v[%d] es: %d\n", i, v[i]);
    }
}
```